# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found - Android gradlew test failing on Github Action

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, github-actions

Android Gradle Test is failing on Github Actions but working fine on local machine.

Command:

`./gradlew test`

Error logs (Github Actions CI/CD):

```
bash ./gradlew test
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/17.0.10-7/x64
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
..............................................................................................................
Unzipping /home/runner/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.4.2-bin/48ivgl02cpt2ed3fh9dbalvx8/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip to /home/runner/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.4.2-bin/48ivgl02cpt2ed3fh9dbalvx8
Set executable permissions for: /home/runner/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.4.2-bin/48ivgl02cpt2ed3fh9dbalvx8/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle

Welcome to Gradle 7.4.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Aggregated test and JaCoCo reports
 - Marking additional test source directories as tests in IntelliJ
 - Support for Adoptium JDKs in Java toolchains

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/runner/work/customer-android-app/customer-android-app/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Gradle file (Plugin Section):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

}
```

Anyone can help on this?